# How to set up function syntax

Tags: scheme

I am trying to set up a part of this function because there are multiple parts to the equation. I keep getting the error of `application: not a procedure`and the equation looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQftm.png) and it supposed to be translated into a scheme function. My function currently looks like this:

`((and (> m 0) (> n 0) ack(- m 1) (ack(m (- n 1)))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lispy languages parentheses are always meaningful and you can have neither too few nor too many.

In your case you start with a double open parenthesis `((and ...` meaning you want to perform `and` and then call the resulting function. You probably want to remove one outer pair of parentheses.

Secondly, in Lisp you call functions with `(fun arg1 arg2 ...)` syntax, not `fun (arg1 arg2 ...)`, so your `ack(- m 1) (ack(m (- n 1))` bit should probably be `(ack (- m 1) (ack m (- n 1)))`.